# How can I get a listitem/page related resources from code behind

Tags: list, development, powershell, codebehind

In the GUI it is possible to get the resources used by a page as shown by the image.
Now I would like to get this information in the code behind so that I can modify only pages that are using a specific image.
Where is this data stored?

[image: Image showing related resources]

Comment: are you using Server Side Code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: *I don't know how that specific functionality is implemented, so it is possible that there exist a simpler way to achieve the same results as my proposed solution.*

Looking at SharePoint object model, the only way that comes to mind to achieve that is to work backwards - checking for each file if it has a relation to the original listitem.
The `SPFile` object exposes the [`BackwardLinks`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.backwardlinks.aspx) property which represents the list of files that "utilize" the current checked one.

This means that for example it is possible to use this property to check if a page layout is in use: the `BackwardLinks` property would include all pages that use the inspected layout.

I can only assume that the "related files" functionality works by accessing that property. Basically, when you use it on a file it scans the site collection for other files whose `BackwardLinks` collection contains a reference to the original one.

Anyway - to achieve your goal, **modify only pages that are using a specific image** it should be sufficient to check the `BackwardLinks` property on the `SPFile` instance representing the target image.